# SQL Server 2008 : Update table records from one database to another database present on two different servers

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two databases with the same schema, name, stored procedures, same tables, same records on two different servers.

For example database `test` is present on following mentioned servers with everything same including data. server 1 = 123.155.12.1 and server 2 = 123.155.12.2

Now I need to update records in table on server 2 accordingly if there is any update done in same table on server 1. For this any query syntax exists..?

(excluding replication option) if yes please help me with example.

Thanks in advance!

Regards.
Aksh

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Akki you could make use of the OPENQUERY option to achieve this, I am not sure if you want to perform this action for every update done on the Table in SERVER1 or if this is just a one time update.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need to do this for every update on the Table in Server 1.